# Javascript JSON Display data corresponding to option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to display data depending on the selected option. Below is the code. The dropbox is populated with `name = "John","Damon","Patrick" and "Mark"`. Now depending on the selection I want to display the corresponding related data. for example, if i select Mark from the option, the corresponding data  `"points": 13654,"color": "#DAF0FD","bullet": "3.gif"` should be stored in an array or one more JSON object. At the end i need to plot the graph.
I have around `1000` records.

```
<html>
  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

      select = document.getElementById("selector");
      var lookup = {};
      var items = chartData;
      //alert(items)
      for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
        var name = item.name;
        if (!(name in lookup)) {
          lookup[name]=1;
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = i+1;
          option.textContent = name;
          select.appendChild(option);
        }; 
      };
    };        

    // note, each data item has "bullet" field.
    var chartData = [{
        "name": "John",
            "points": 35654,
            "color": "#7F8DA9",
        "bullet": "0.gif"
    }, {
        "name": "Damon",
            "points": 65456,
            "color": "#FEC514",
            "bullet": "1.gif"
    }, {
        "name": "Patrick",
            "points": 45724,
            "color": "#DB4C3C",
            "bullet": "2.gif"
    }, {
        "name": "Mark",
            "points": 13654,
            "color": "#DAF0FD",
            "bullet": "3.gif"
    }
```

{
            "name": "Patrick",
                "points": 53421,
                "color": "#DB4C3C",
                "bullet": "2.gif"
        },{
            "name": "Mark",
                "points": 12311,
                "color": "#DAF0FD",
                "bullet": "3.gif"
        }];

```
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div><select id="selector"><option value="99">Default</option></select></div>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx3ew/1/), I would suggest using some thing like JQuery to add event listeners, otherwise you need to handle IE separately in your JS code. I have used underscore for data manipulations.

```
       // note, each data item has "bullet" field.
var chartData = [{
    "name": "John",
        "points": 35654,
        "color": "#7F8DA9",
        "bullet": "0.gif"
}, {
    "name": "John",
        "points": 35654,
        "color": "#7F8DA9",
        "bullet": "0.gif"
},{
    "name": "John",
        "points": 35654,
        "color": "#7F8DA9",
        "bullet": "0.gif"
},{
    "name": "Damon",
        "points": 65456,
        "color": "#FEC514",
        "bullet": "1.gif"
}, {
    "name": "Patrick",
        "points": 45724,
        "color": "#DB4C3C",
        "bullet": "2.gif"
},{
    "name": "Patrick",
        "points": 45724,
        "color": "#DB4C3C",
        "bullet": "2.gif"
},{
    "name": "Patrick",
        "points": 45724,
        "color": "#DB4C3C",
        "bullet": "2.gif"
},{
    "name": "Patrick",
        "points": 45724,
        "color": "#DB4C3C",
        "bullet": "2.gif"
}, {
    "name": "Mark",
        "points": 13654,
        "color": "#DAF0FD",
        "bullet": "3.gif"
}];


var select = document.getElementById("selector");
var lookup = {};


var uniqNames = _.unique(_.pluck(chartData, 'name'));
var len = uniqNames.length;

//alert(items)
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var name = uniqNames[i];
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = name;
    option.textContent = name;
    select.appendChild(option);
};


select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var selValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selValue === 'None') {
        return;
    }
    var selectedOptions = _.where(chartData, {name:selValue})
    alert(JSON.stringify(selectedOptions))

})
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I have mentioned, I have around 1000 data points in which for example: John has 50 records "name": "John",
            "points": 35654,
            "color": "#7F8DA9",
        "bullet": "0.gif"
    },"name": "John",
            "points": 6786,
            "color": "#7F8DA9",
        "bullet": "0.gif"
    },  etc,so I need to retrieve  all the data

Comment: updated answer, using underscore library for data manipulations.