# Javascript return variable from addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
    var jobj = [];
    var keyChartData = null;
    var chartData = [{
        "name": "John",
        "points": 35654,
        "color": "#7F8DA9",
        "bullet": "0.gif"
    }, {
        "name": "Damon",
        "points": 65456,
        "color": "#FEC514",
        "bullet": "1.gif"
    }, {
        "name": "Patrick",
        "points": 45724,
        "color": "#DB4C3C",
        "bullet": "2.gif"
    }, {
        "name": "Mark",
        "points": 13654,
        "color": "#DAF0FD",
        "bullet": "3.gif"
    } {
        "name": "Mark",
        "points": 43244,
        "color": "#DAF0FD",
        "bullet": "3.gif"
    } {
        "name": "Patrick",
        "points": 64643,
        "color": "#DB4C3C",
        "bullet": "2.gif"
    }, {
        "name": "Patrick",
        "points": 73724,
        "color": "#DB4C3C",
        "bullet": "2.gif"
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "points": 65672,
        "color": "#DB4C3C",
        "bullet": "2.gif"
    }, ];

    var select = document.getElementById("selector");
    var lookup = {};
    var len = chartData.length;


    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var item = chartData[i];
        var name = item.name;
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = i;
        option.textContent = name;
        select.appendChild(option);
    };


    select.addEventListener('change', function () {
        var selValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].name;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         var item = chartData[i];

          var name = item.name;
          //alert("selValue: "+selValue+" Key: " +key);

        if(selValue === name){
        jobj.push(JSON.stringify(chartData[i]));
       } 
      } 
       keyChartData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jobj));

    })

alert(keyChartData);

AmCharts.ready(function () {

     // SERIAL CHART    
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/";
    chart.dataProvider = keyChartData;
..........
}
```

This is with reference to [Javascript JSON Display data corresponding to option selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786152/javascript-json-display-data-corresponding-to-option-selected). which I had asked y'day. Thank you for the solution, I could solve the problem. But now, I have keyChartData declared as global variable, Now I load the JSON data depending on the selected option and store it to keyChartData, which i nedd to capture in  AmCharts.ready function to plot the graph. Outsite the function the value of keyChartdata is blank,   how to go about this hurdle. Kindly help.

Comment: Is there any way to reload `AmCharts` when keyChartData changes?

Answer (score 0):

keyChartdata is not blacnk outside the handler. It is blank just when ready called.

Try to add "console.log(1);" to change handler and "console.log(2);" to ready handler. Perhaps  you will see "2" and then "1". You have to fire ready before exiting from change handler or just call another function which will create AmCharts.AmSerialChart and copy keyChartData to chart.dataProvider.